# Spring data JPA findOne() retorna null

Tags: java, mvc, spring

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação utilizando Spring MVC, com spring data jpa na camada de persistência.

Quando eu tento fazer uma pesquisa utilizando o método `findOne` (ou `findById`) returna sempre null.

Já verifiquei no banco de dados e existe o registro cadastrado com o Id indicado.

Chamada do método:

```
public Atividade findById(short id) {
    return atividades.findOne(id);
}
```

Erro ao tentar pesquisar:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: null
>       at br.com.transformare.service.AtividadeService.findById(AtividadeService.java:32)

Alguém sabe me dizer se seria algum erro no meu código ou algum bug do spring data?

Comment: Coloque mais trechos do código. Somente com isso que informou e difícil ter noção. Copie de preferencia o método que esta invocando "atividades.findOne(id)" e também onde apresenta o erro (AtividadeService.java:32)

Comment: Parece que teu objeto "atividades" não foi instanciado/injetado. Como bem observado pelo @Doug, coloque o código completo da classe.

Answer (score 0):

Provavelmente o id não está recebendo o valor passado pela requisição. Nesse caso, utilize a anotação `@PathVariable` para indicar que o id virá na URI da requisição. Na versão atual do Spring Data, o método findOne não é compatível com o que você mostrou. Dê preferência ao findById com orElse.

Exemplo:

```
public Atividade findById(@PathVariable short id) {
    return atividades.findById(id).orElse(null);
}
```

Não esqueça também de fazer o mapeamento da requisição acima do método, como por exemplo: `@GetMapping("/{id}")`

Answer (score 0):

O erro acontece, pois como o id não está sendo capturado ele faz um find de algo que não existe, um numero indefinido, e logo gera uma Excpetion NullPointerException, se quiser fazer o teste para confirmar pode verificar se o numero for diferente de null ai poderá fazer o find.

Com seu repositório em mãos vamos explicar as coisas da forma correta no spring.

precisamos definir em nossa rota (uri) de recebimento o id que vai chegar, logo após iremos capturar com o @Pathvariable, ou seja se chegar 1 vai passar para o id esse 1, logo depois podemos usar o spring para tratar o retorno de uma forma mais elegante, lembrando que é bom sempre trabalharmos nesse caso de retorno com ResponseEntity

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/atividade")
public class AtividadeController {
// other methods

    @Autowired
    Atividade atividadeRepository;

    @GetMapping("/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<Atividade> findOneAtividadeById(@PathVariable short id) {
        return this.atividadesRepository.findById(id).map(atividade -> ResponseEntity.ok(atividade))
                .orElse(ResponseEntity.notFound().build());
    }
}
```

sua rota ficaria então por exemplo: GET -> localhost:8080/atividade/1

lembrando que o short vai de -32,768 até 32,767 usar um Integer traz benefícios pois como Integer é um Object no Java então fica facil utilizar suas funções.

Answer (score -1):

Cria um repositório com a seguinte chamada no banco

```
Atividade findById(short id)
```

e use ela lugar do `findOne`

Dica: trabalhe id como Long e não como short

Comment: ID como int também seria ruim?

Comment: Depende muito da aplicação. Se é uma aplicação muito grande em que vão existir milhares de registros, o ideal seria usar o Long. Aqui está a diferença dos dois.
int vai de –2.147.483.648 até 2.147.483.647
Long vai de de –9.223.372.036.854.775.808 até 9.223.372.036.854.775.807
Pra não termos que nos preocupar com estouro de memória por que o id não suporta muito caracteres, melhor o Long.